# Confusing variable update in python

Tags: python, variables, sudoku

So I was reading Peter Norvig [**Solving Every Sudoku Puzzle**](http://norvig.com/sudoku.html), while doing he said the he updated the values by calling the function assign. I could not understand how is the variable **values** being updated by the function **assign** if there's no assignment to the variable values.  Is values passed by reference to the assign function.

Here is the code in question:

```
def parse_grid(grid):
"""Convert grid to a dict of possible values, {square: digits}, or
return False if a contradiction is detected."""
## To start, every square can be any digit; then assign values from the grid.
values = dict((s, digits) for s in squares)
for s,d in grid_values(grid).items():
    if d in digits and not assign(values, s, d):
        return False ## (Fail if we can't assign d to square s.)

def assign(values, s, d):
    """Eliminate all the other values (except d) from values[s] and propagate.
    Return values, except return False if a contradiction is detected."""
    other_values = values[s].replace(d, '')
    if all(eliminate(values, s, d2) for d2 in other_values):
        return values
    else:
        return False
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`assign()` carries out the assignment of a number to a square by exploring its consequences: the elimination of alternative answers. All the modifications are done in `eliminate()`, which you don't include in your code snippet. The first step (after checking whether anything needs to be done) is to eliminate value `d` from position `s`:

```
def eliminate(values, s, d):
    """Eliminate d from values[s]; propagate when values or places <= 2.
    Return values, except return False if a contradiction is detected."""
    if d not in values[s]:
        return values ## Already eliminated
    values[s] = values[s].replace(d,'')
    ...
```

There's the assignment you were looking for. This is executed for each `d2` that `assign()` hands over to `eliminate()`. (Then `eliminate()` calls itself recursively, to remove even more values). So there's no wholesale replacement of the dictionary, but its contents are modified one by one.

Arguments are passed by reference in python, so all these calls manipulate the same dictionary. New dictionaries are only created in `search()`, with the explicit call to `values.copy()`.  Both `assign()` and `eliminate()` always return a reference to the same dictionary object that they were given (unless they return `False`, of course). In fact, as far as I can tell, `eliminate()` might just as well return `True/False`, since its return value is only ever checked in a boolean way; the caller already has access to the dictionary that was passed in.

Comment: @chepner, this line is copy-pasted from `eliminate( )` and it is exactly as I wrote it.

Comment: I think what I would like to know is if values is passed by reference to the assign function

Comment: Yes, all arguments are passed by reference in python.